# Change TableView colors from a separate ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I am simply making a switch which will change the colors on a tableview.

I have the MasterViewController, which has the 'tableview' colors, data, etc. I also have the Settings controller, which is called InfoViewController, which has the switch.

I am not able to change the values of the color from the InfoViewController.

InfoViewController switch code:

```
-(IBAction)switch:(id)sender
{
    MasterViewController *destViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ElementCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [destViewController.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (color == @"Black") {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        destViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        destViewController.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }else if(color == @"White"){
        destViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        destViewController.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

I am using storyboards.

Comment: You have 2 view controllers, how are you switching between them?

Answer (score 0):

You have got a new instance of `MasterViewController` and did nothing to it， you should change the value of the instance already in the memory

Comment: Everytime I run this and try the switch, I get a sigabrt saying it cannot find the file MasterViewController in bundle blah blah

Comment: And I am very confused about your answer. I want to modify TableView properties from a viewcontroller that it isnt housed in.

Comment: @Keaton what have you done to the new alloc instance `destViewController`

Comment: destViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        destViewController.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: @Keaton I mean the instance is just used in this method, and is there any connection between the new alloc instance and the controller on your screen